# How to find the number of purchases over time intervals SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas, amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift (Postgres), and Pandas to do my work. I'm trying to get the number of user actions, lets say purchases to make it easier to understand. I have a table, purchases that holds the following data:

```
user_id, timestamp ,  price
1,     , 2015-02-01,  200
1,     , 2015-02-02,  50
1,     , 2015-02-10,  75
```

ultimately I would like the number of purchases over a certain timestamp. Such as

```
userid, 28-14_days, 14-7_days, 7
```

Here is what I have so far, I'm aware I don't have an upper limit on the dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x_days.user_id, SUM(x_days.purchases) AS x_num, SUM(y_days.purchases) AS y_num,
x_days.x_date, y_days.y_date
FROM 
(
SELECT purchases.user_id, COUNT(purchases.user_id) as purchases, 
                                    DATE(purchases.timestamp) as x_date
FROM purchases
WHERE  purchases.timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '%(x_days_ago)s day') AND
purchases.max_value > 200
GROUP BY DATE(purchases.timestamp), purchases.user_id
) AS x_days
JOIN
(
    SELECT purchases.user_id, COUNT(purchases.user_id) as purchases, 
                                    DATE(purchases.timestamp) as y_date
    FROM purchases
    WHERE  purchases.timestamp > (current_date - INTERVAL '%(y_days_ago)s    day') AND
    purchases.max_value > 200
    GROUP BY DATE(purchases.timestamp), purchases.user_id) AS y_days 
    ON
    x_days.user_id = y_days.user_id
GROUP BY
x_days.user_id, x_days.x_date, y_days.y_date

params={'x_days_ago':x_days_ago, 'y_days_ago':y_days_ago}
where these are set in python/pandas
```

x_days_ago = 14
y_days_ago = 7

But this didn't work out exactly as planned:

```
    user_id x_num   y_num   x_date      y_date
0   5451772 1       1       2015-02-10  2015-02-10
1   5026678 1       1       2015-02-09  2015-02-09
2   6337993 2       1       2015-02-14  2015-02-13
3   6204432 1       3       2015-02-10  2015-02-11
4   3417539 1       1       2015-02-11  2015-02-11
```

Even though I don't have an upper date to look between (so x is effectively searching from 14 days to now and y is 7 days to now, meaning overlap), in some cases y is higher.

Can anyone help me either fix this or give me a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most efficient answer, but you can generate each sum with a sub-select:

```
WITH
  summed AS (
    SELECT user_id, day, COUNT(1) AS purchases
      FROM (SELECT user_id, DATE(timestamp) AS day FROM purchases) AS _
     GROUP BY user_id, day
  ),
  users AS (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM purchases)
SELECT user_id,
       (SELECT SUM(purchases) FROM summed
         WHERE summed.user_id = users.user_id
           AND day >= DATE(NOW() - interval ' 7 days')) AS days_7,
       (SELECT SUM(purchases) FROM summed
         WHERE summed.user_id = users.user_id
           AND day >= DATE(NOW() - interval '14 days')) AS days_14
  FROM users;
```

(This was tested in Postgres, not in Redshift; but the Redshift documentation suggests that both `WITH` and `DISTINCT` are supported.) I would have liked to do this with a window, to obtain rolling sums; but it's a little onerous without `generate_series()`.

Comment: Thanks @solidsnack, but according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-sql-implementated-differently.html redshift doesn't support WITH

Comment: It says `WITH` is not supported in conjunction with `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`. See the docs for `WITH` under `SELECT`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html "A `WITH` clause is an optional clause that precedes the `SELECT` list in a query."